# Does adding too many generics can cause typescipt performance issues

Tags: typescript, express, typescript-generics

I heard that having too many generics can cause "Extremely slow compilation"

In my code I would like to create a new Request type for express that I use in all my controllers

Is it a good practise ? or can I have some performance or other issues

My type

```
import { Request } from 'express';

export interface ExpressRequest<TOUTPUT = any, TPARAMS = any, TBODY = any, TQUERYPARAMS = any>
  extends Request<TPARAMS, any, TBODY, TQUERYPARAMS> {
  output?: TOUTPUT;
}
```

I have 200+ routes where I want to add this ExpressRequest type

Here is a code exemple of how I use it on express routes

```
import express, { NextFunction, Request, Response } from 'express';
import * as core from 'express-serve-static-core';
const app = express();
const port = 3000;
app.use(express.json());

export interface ExpressRequest<TOUTPUT = any, TPARAMS = core.ParamsDictionary, TBODY = any, TQUERYPARAMS = any>
  extends Request<TPARAMS, any, TBODY, TQUERYPARAMS> {
  output?: TOUTPUT;
}

export type Message = {
  message: string;
};

export type User = {
  name: string;
  age: number;
};

app.get('/message/:message', (req: ExpressRequest<Message, Message>, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
  const message = req.params.message;
  req.output = { message };
  console.log({ message });
  next();
});

app.post('/createUser', (req: ExpressRequest<User, any, User>, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
  const user: User = req.body;
  req.output = user;
  console.log({ user });
  console.log('User has been created !');
  next();
});

// Middlewares
app.use((req: ExpressRequest, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
  res.json(req.output);
});

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}`);
});
```

Comment: If your types are more complicated the compiler has more work to do and the compilation process might be slower. However, this has no impact on the runtime performance of your code. The only issue I see (maybe) is that the first generic default parameter of `Request` is `core.ParamsDictionary` but you pass in `any` by default.

Comment: I don't think we have enough information to answer this. It's impossible to know whether you will have performance problems without a [mre]. My guess is that the type you've written would have no problems, but that's just a guess and not suitable for Stack Overflow. Could you please [edit] this question so that it is clearly amenable to an objectively correct answer as opposed to conjecture?

Comment: I've added more details :)

Comment: I don't know enough about express to judge this code, but it does look like there are [a bunch of errors](https://tsplay.dev/wedj1W) unrelated to your question. You might want to clear them up, especially because compiler performance could well be affected by compile time errors.